# How do I beat medium AI in 5 minutes?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I would like to get 'beat medium AI in 5 minutes' achievement. Usually I am playing as terran.

Is there special SMALL (TINY) map for that? What is strategy for that? Should I build 1st barrack on opponents base? Should I play some special race against another special?

Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Makes ya wish the Computer's would leave the game after they wish ya "GG".

Comment: I have a replay of me cannon rushing the Insane AI for getting all those achievements. Unfortunately I'm not home now, but I'll try to upload it later.

Comment: @Juan not sure how long ago that was but Insane AI seems to be very good at swarming your builder with plenty of workers to kill it and everything else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As **Terran** against Protoss, you can do a fast proxy barracks bunker rush on a small map like Steps Of War.

To begin the game, mine with your SCVs and build one SCV from you command center. Set the rally point of your command center to your opponents base so that the new SCV immediately starts going there. Don't build any more SCVs than this one.

As soon as you have 100 minerals start building a supply depot and shift-click the building SCV so that he also moves to the opponents base as soon as his supply depot is finished.

Around the time you have 150 minerals the first SCV you sent across the map should reach the opponents base. Start building barracks there. Against medium AI you don't even have to hide the barracks, he won't attack with his workers. Once the second SCV reaches his base, build a second barracks with it.

[image: Barracks]

As soon as the first barracks is finished, that SCV should start building a bunker. Put it somewhere close to the mineral line, don't be shy about it:

[image: Bunker]

Then put the rally point of your barracks on that bunker and start producing marines as soon as possible. If your bunker gets attacked repair it with you two SCVs and basically just keep producing marines until the computer gives up:

[image: Marines]

Comment: That work's, I did this way. Thanks. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to deal with AI in 5 minutes on very hard, so used Protoss for that.

Answer (score 23):

So here was my thoughts when I approached this problem:

- How do I give myself the biggest advantage when rushing
- How do I hurt my opponent the most by rushing

In respect to the first thought, shorter maps are definitely better (you were on the right track there), so I chose steps of war.  With respect to the second thought I decided to pick a Terran opponent.  Marines (the starting Terran unit) benefit a lot more from larger groups than their Zealot and Zergling equivalents so in early game, when we won't have large groups, it makes sense to go for a Terran opponent.

[image]

Next I tried to pick a very fast strategy: 8 Pool.  I decided on the 8 Pool because I happened to know that you can sustain Zergling production (with a Queen) off of 8 Drones (I don't remember the Zealot equivalent I think its also 8 though).

[image]

I build 6 initial Zerglings to put some initial pressure (and stop him from building up Marines) and then I go for my Queen/2nd Ovi.  The goal of these first 6 Zerglings needs to be something simple (because I still need to Macro) and needs to stop the Terran from mounting a defense.  So I'm going to specifically kill the Marines.

[image]

I'm also a pretty good player so I'll even harass the SCVs; however, this is more complicated.  I can't let any of my Zerglings die, because I need to build up critical mass and he has enough SCVs to wipe them out, so what I do is a little [Brinkmanship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brinkmanship), try to lure a few away and kill them off.

[image]

You'll notice my reinforcements are starting to come in, and eventually spawn larva will kick in.  As more Zerglings come in, I get progressively more aggressive till, finally, I'm chasing down the few remaining SCVs.  After some Magical threshold, the computer GGs.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Wish I could extra +1 for the pics and commentary.

Comment: this is a very good post, but would be better if it showed him how to win as Terran.  This is a good write up for Zerg, but may not help a low level Terran player.

Comment: Could you do ZvZ and just crawler rush?  I did a ZvZZ (hard AI) for kicks and built 2x spine crawlers on each of their creep before they had a queen/lings (drones did not attack at all).  If you put 4 on one base that will be real quick.

Comment: @Aardvark I mentioned in the post that picking Terran would be intrinsically harder.  I could do a similar write up though and see if I can get something posted tonight.

Comment: I would do it, but I'm currently at work.  I have done this achievement with relative ease as a Terran player.  I know you play zerg, but a 2x 12 proxy rax at the natural on steppes of war is a pretty easy way to do it.  This can lead easily to a bunker rush.  The strat is easier against protoss due to the ability to kite the early zealots with mass marines

Answer (score 6):

The only way you will be able to do this is with a Photon Cannon/Bunker-Reaper/Spine Crawler rush.  The easiest way for me was to use a Spine Crawler rush against a Zerg AI opponent.

Choose a small 2 player map like Jungle Basin or Steppes of War.  **Do not** choose one of the Novice maps as they block your entrance with destructible rocks.

At the start of the game, begin harvesting minerals but **do not** build any drones.  Wait until you have 200 minerals and then morph a Spawning Pool (also known as a 6 pool, because you have 6 drones when you being morphing the Spawning Pool).  While the Spawning Pool is morphing, continue to make drones until you get to 10.

Once the Spawning Pool is complete, send 2 drones to the enemy base.  By the time they get there, you should have 200 minerals saved up.  Move them near the hatchery and morph both of them into Spine Crawlers.  Get them close enough that they can hit the enemy drones and the Spawning Pool as well.  While the Spine Crawlers are morphing in, build 4 Zerglings and set your Hatchery rally point next to your Spine Crawlers.  This will be enough of a force for the AI to call "gg" (good game) in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to defeat the medium AI Medium in under 5 minutes or less (average of 3 minutes):

- choose Protoss race
- when the game starts, select 1 probe to go to your opponent's base
- build 2 more additional probes
- build a Pylon on their base, near their collector zone (let the AI to be Terran or Protoss)
- build a Forge, then spam the Cannon! Do this as quickly as possible until the AI says gg.

You can also do this plan against the hard AI, but against the very hard AI, you will need to build outside their sight, or their probe will attack your building.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a replay](http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays/117081-1v1-protoss-xelnaga-caverns) on how to do it for Insane A.I.

Of course this works for any A.I., but getting it for Insane gets you all the rest.

http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays/117081-1v1-protoss-xelnaga-caverns